# On FreeBSD, why is chmod +t on a non-directory a privileged operation?

Tags: unix, freebsd, chmod

On FreeBSD, `chmod +t file` is a privileged operation if `file` is not a directory:

```
$ echo >test
$ chmod +t test
chmod: test: Inappropriate file type or format
$ su
Password:
# chmod +t test
# ls -l test
-rw-r--r-T  1 fuz  wheel  1 Jan 26 12:44 test
```

**chmod**(2) documents this behaviour:

```
 [EFTYPE]           The effective user ID is not the super-user, the mode
                    includes the sticky bit (S_ISVTX), and path does not
                    refer to a directory.
```

Meanwhile, **sticky**(7) explains that `S_ISVTX` is ignored if `file` is not a directory:

```
 A special file mode, called the sticky bit (mode S_ISTXT), is used to
 indicate special treatment for directories.  It is ignored for regular
 files.  See chmod(2) or the file <sys/stat.h> for an explanation of file
 modes.
```

What is the historical or technical reason why marking a non-directory as sticky on FreeBSD is a privileged operation? Why was an extra error code `EFTYPE` invented for this where it should have been `EPERM` or `ENOTDIR`?

Comment: Historically, the original Unix disallowed this. The [V7 chmod](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/man/man2/chmod.2) man page says "Ability to set this bit is restricted to the super-user
since swap space is consumed
by the images". I cannot say why descendants chose to retain this prohibition even though they don't support the functionality. OpenBSD also forbids non-root users from setting the sticky bit on files, returning EFTYPE. Solaris silently ignores attempts by non-root users to set the sticky bit on files (the chmod() returns 0 but has no effect).

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Can you turn this into an answer? This answers my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Historically, the original Unix disallowed this. The [V7 chmod man page](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/man/man2/chmod.2) says

> Ability to set this bit is restricted to the super-user since swap space is consumed by the images

The [V7 chmod system call](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/sys/sys/sys4.c) didn't return an error if the user tried to set the sticky bit, though, it just silently turned off the bit:

```
if (u.u_uid)
    uap->fmode &= ~ISVTX;
```

This behavior was carried over unchanged to the BSDs. [4.3BSD](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=4.3BSD/usr/src/sys/sys/ufs_syscalls.c) has this code, which silently turns off the ISVTX bit on non-directories for non-root users:

```
if (u.u_uid) {
    if ((ip->i_mode & IFMT) != IFDIR)
        mode &= ~ISVTX;
    ...
}
```

The code was changed in [4.4BSD](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=4.4BSD/usr/src/sys/ufs/ufs/ufs_vnops.c) to return the error `EFTYPE`, although the [4.4BSD chmod man page](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=4.4BSD/usr/share/man/cat2/chmod.0) doesn't mention it. I don't know why it was changed.

```
if (cred->cr_uid) {
    if (vp->v_type != VDIR && (mode & ISVTX))
        return (EFTYPE);
    ...
}
```

[FreeBSD 1.0](http://ftp-archive.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD-Archive/old-releases/i386/1.0-RELEASE/tarballs/srcdist/) contains the same code as 4.4BSD.

```
if (cred->cr_uid) {
    if (vp->v_type != VDIR && (mode & ISVTX))
         return (EFTYPE);
    ...
}
```

This has carried over to current releases. [FreeBSD 10.2](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/release/10.2.0/sys/ufs/ufs/ufs_vnops.c?revision=286717) has this:

```
if (vp->v_type != VDIR && (mode & S_ISTXT)) {
    if (priv_check_cred(cred, PRIV_VFS_STICKYFILE, 0))
        return (EFTYPE);
}
```

[OpenBSD](http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/~checkout~/src/sys/ufs/ufs/ufs_vnops.c?rev=1.123) has similar code:

```
if (cred->cr_uid) {
    if (vp->v_type != VDIR && (mode & S_ISTXT))
        return (EFTYPE);
    ...
}
```

Solaris 10 silently ignores attempts by non-root users to set the sticky bit on files. (I will add source code snippets when available.)

Answer (score 0):

> What is the historical or technical reason why marking a non-directory as sticky on FreeBSD is a privileged operation?

Why should it be not? First, it's clearly not an operation which makes sense, and as such it should be reported to a user as a failure, to indicate he's doing something wrong. Also, allowing it is not future proof as with any unused flag or field - it may be used for something in future, and not to pose security or consistency risk, it should be in a predictable state.

> Why was an extra error code EFTYPE invented for this where it should have been EPERM or ENOTDIR?

See errno(2). EFTYPE is not invented specifically for this case, has wider meaning, and is more suitable for this case than EPERM, while ENOTDIR has completely unrelated purpose.

Comment: All other systems I tested allow an arbitrary user to set a file as sticky. This is in coincidence with the historic meaning of the sticky-bit for binaries (retain binary in swap space). FreeBSD is the only outlier. Your post does not give a reasonable explanation and fails to provide source for its claims. Downvote.

Comment: Oh yeah, and `chmod` (and its variants) is the only system call that ever sets `errno` to `EFTYPE`.

Comment: Syscalls are not the only place where standard error codes are used.

Comment: Sadly, `EFTYPE` isn't part of any standard I found.